# MS SQL Express - Memory limitation vs. web application

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory-management, licensing

I have web application that will be similar to forums. I plan to have few thousands+ users on this application, and i wonder if i can use MS SQL Express - here is the list of it's limitations:
[image: SQLExpr limitations]

Despite the cpu usage, i wonder if this 1 GB of memory usage is enough. Can anyone tell me if this might be enough, or maybe give me some examples when this 1 GB would be enough.

Comment: This is off topic for this site. Try either dba.StackExchange.com or ServerFault.com

Comment: Okay, thanks, sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be fine. Depending on how many columns you have in each row and their types, you should be able to get at least 1 million rows into 1GB of disk space. The database will only load as much of that table as it needs in memory. If it reaches its memory limit it will start paging.

If you are using SQL 2008 R2, then the actual database can only grow up to 10GB which is the real limit you should be concerned about.

In our database, our tables that are around 1GB contain about 4 million rows. We have 2 databases that are 50GB and the one takes up 16GB of RAM and the other 2GB. So it depends on how often and which tables are accessed.